# MAMP - running php-fpm as a different user

Tags: php, mamp

I am wanting to change the user from **root** to **user1** but I can't find where the config file is for php-fpm in nginx inside the MAMP directory.

The reason I want to run it as a non root user is because when I upload a file it is created with permissions of the root user but my MAMP folder itself is under **user1** and that means that a script that is running under root will never be able to read this file. If I use **apache** in MAMP it works perfectly because it automatically executes **php** under **user1** like it should.

Comment: Okay the problem is that NGINX is forced by mamp to run under root and if you edit the nginx.conf to change it, then when you restart mamp it just reverts back, where as Apache runs under the normal user that you login with from the beginning so you never have to change it. This is why scripts under Apache work where as NGINX it does not.